# Form Inside Fancybox 2 Loses Focus

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Can't focus on the input fields of an inner form for FancyBox2.

The following code actually focuses on the first input of the form when the fancybox opens, but then I can't focus on any other input, when I try to click on other input focus goes back to the original input.

When I deleted the "aftershow" function can't focus on any input at all.

Example page where this code is running, it's an exit pop-over try to leave the page, fancybox will appear but you cant focus on the inputs

Anyone?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
$(".fancybox-button").fancybox({
    prevEffect: 'none',
    nextEffect: 'none',
    closeBtn: false,
    helpers: {
        title: {
            type: 'inside',
            position: 'top'
        },
        buttons: {},
        overlay: {
            css: {
                'background': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95)'
            }
        }
    }
});

$(".various2").fancybox({
    afterShow: function() {
jQuery('.fancybox-inner').contents().find('#email').focus()
},      
    topRatio:0,
    leftRatio:0,
    fitToView: true,
    autoSize: true,
    closeClick: false,
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none',
    padding: 0,
    overlay: {
        css: {
            'background': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95)'
        }
    }


});


});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `#inline` as both the trigger button and the slideshow container. Therefore, clicks inside of the form are bubbling up and re-triggering the button, thus reshowing fancybox and re-triggering afterShow. See in the [fancybox demo](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples) how a.various and div#inline are two different things?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is the case. Please read through the answer again carefully and think about how the focus would be reset to the first input on every click in the div due to bubbling

Comment: @sebas : Clayton is right, you should replace this line of your code `$("#inline").trigger('click')` by this `$(".various2 ").trigger('click')`

Comment: @JFK Are you sure? Isn't that still the same element? I was saying use a second element as the button.

Comment: @JFK I replaced that, same result, didn't work. Can't focus on the inputs :S

Comment: @ClaytonLeis : the button that triggers fancybox is `.various2 `

Comment: @sebas : I still see `$("#inline").trigger('click');` in your demo page